# Could not reserve enough space for object heap: Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, jvm, heap-memory

This is occurring in Android Studio during "gradlew build".

Error: "Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 3174400KB object heap" (3.18GB)

I've tried -Xmx and the object heap has always expanded to surpass. My 32 bit software can't go much further.

"org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxHeapSize=4000m -Xmx4000m" was added to the gradle properties file.

The project folder itself only takes up 1.1GB so I'm confused as to how this is even possible.

Update:
This issue seems to have resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

add : `android:largeHeap="true"` to manifests

```
 <application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:largeHeap="true">
```

Comment: Unfortunately this problem seems to have resolved itself.